# Making a responsive popup that appears on table row click

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

I'm using the following code to make a popup on each table row, but I can't center the popup on the screen and obviously it's not responsive.

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLx4Y/47/)

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Categories</th>
                <th>Sub-Categories</th>
                <th>Counts</th>
                <th>description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="popupOpen" data-href="#entry1">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Category 1</td>
                <td>Sub-Category 1</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>This is a test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Category 2</td>
                <td>Sub-Category 2</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>This is a test again</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
<div id="entry1" class="largeWin">
        <a href="#" class="close">X</a>
      <p>some text here...</p>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('tr.popupOpen').click(function() {

    var popup= $(this).attr('data-href');

    $(popup).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border
    var popMargTop = ($(popup).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(popup).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(popup).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});

$('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
  $('#mask , .largeWin').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
}); 
return false;
});
```

How can I center my popup and make it responsive?

Comment: Post your HTML and will be even better if you make fiddle of your code

Comment: @Richa: I updated my question. Please take a look at my code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLx4Y/41/)**

Are you trying to achieve something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr.popupOpen').click(function () {

        var popup = $(this).attr('data-href');

        $(popup).fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border


        $(popup).css({
            'margin-top': '20px',
                'margin-left': '40px'
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('div.container').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function () {
        $('#mask , .largWin').fadeOut(300, function () {
            $('#mask').remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is like this! I said the mask was not working in jsfiddle. (what did you do?) Anyway, the problem is that it is not centered. Specifying margins doesn't make it appear in the center.

Comment: So you can adjust the margin as per you wish to make it centered. If it helped you can always upvote or accept it as answer:)

Comment: I found my mistake and edited my question. check out this: http://jsfiddle.net/TLx4Y/47/ -- I used "var popMargTop = ($(popup).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(popup).width() + 24) / 2;" to center the popup, but it's not working. Your example is not centered either! Try expanding the html section in jsfiddle and you'll see.

Comment: can't you simply adjust px as per your need

Comment: No, It's not a good way and does not work on all display resolutions.