# Popup on click of a column jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968756/making-a-responsive-popup-that-appears-on-table-row-click) stackoverflow post
I was trying to implement the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLx4Y/41/)

Just that instead of applying the click functionality on the whole row, I just have to apply it on a single column.

So instead of

```
$('tr.popupOpen').click(function () {
```

I used

```
$('td.popupOpen').click(function () {
```

and instead of

```
<tr class="popupOpen" data-href="#entry1">
    <td></td>
```

I gave

```
<tr>
    <td class="popupOpen" data-href="#entry1">
```

But I am not able to call the corresponding click method after this change. Can someone let me know what I should be doing to make it work.

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/mq3xbhom/

Comment: What's not working? Your code seems to be correct

Comment: Can you clarify the aim as everyone seems to be a little confused what is actually wrong?

Comment: could you tell me what other changes you did there?

Comment: I am really sorry. it was working already. I think I made some more modifications because of which it was not working

Comment: It's working rigth now or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup works properly based on the changes I mentioned above.